# Loading a 9pnet kernel module to a linux kernel 3.16.6-tinycore64

Tags: linux, mount, 9p

I am trying to use 9p to mount a remote FS. The client machine is a tiny core linux machine. modprobe 9pnet says that module 9pnet cant be found at modules.dep How to add 9p kernel modules to the tiny core linux?

Comment: at first try to find this module `find /lib/modules/`uname -r` -name "9pnet"`
If find fails, try search `find /lib/modules/`uname -r` -name "9p*"`
If module found - you can load it by insmod "full path to module"

if you can't find it, than you should install it.

Comment: it is not there. hmm does installing it requires recompiling the kernel?

Comment: I think yes, i've post an answer to your topic.

Answer (score 0):

at first try to find this module find /lib/modules/uname -r`-name "9pnet"`

If find fails, try search find /lib/modules/uname -r`-name "9p*"` If module found - you can load it by insmod "full path to module"

If you can't find it, than you should install it.

As described [there](http://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/9psetup) i think, you should recompile kernel.